# Swift how to make UIView larger than phone screen- can we have it's size of an image's size then zoom out

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have not enough experience on iOS/swift. I want to make a canvas for drawing image from gallery(which I could from some tutorials) - but cannot make UIView's size same as image size. I had to scale down the image to get in the screen. But I want it other way around. 
Let's say if I want to make a UIView with 1600x1200 (my image size) what I have to do? some example code/idea will be great !!!

Comment: Take a look at UIScrollview

Comment: Thanks - actually it worked for me. I made a UIScrollView and fit a image into that. Also used the TouchBegan  etc func with a flag to draw something on the image. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 1600, height:1200))
```